# NotXMLError: Failed to parse the XML data

Tags: python, biopython, pubmed, rentrez, pubmed-api

I'm trying to use the Entrez module from Biopython to retrive full text articles from PubMed Central. This is my code to do the same.

```
import urllib3
import json
import requests
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio.Entrez import efetch, Parser
print(Parser.__file__)
pmcid = 'PMC2837563'

def print_text(pmcid):
    handle = efetch(db='pmc', id=pmcid, retmode='xml', rettype=None)
    #print(handle.read())
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    print(record)

print_text(pmcid)
```

handle.read() works which means the data is being fetched properly. But, I'm not able to do `Entrez.read(handle)` to convert the fetched data into a python object. It gives me the below error:

```
NotXMLError: Failed to parse the XML data (syntax error: line 1036, column 69). Please make sure that the input data are in XML format.
```

Could someone tell me what to do about this? This seems to be correct syntax as per the biopython documentation.

Comment: Do you want to get pdf or just plain text?

Comment: Just plain text would be better

Comment: You cannot get articles texts through `Entrez`, just abstracts. If you want only full text specifically, I can attach the answer with a script that downloads a pdf & goes on to extract plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the last available Biopython version (1.79) does not recognise DTD with *uri* http://www.niso.org/schemas/ali/1.0/. The GitHub version has the corrected *Parser* but it is not available from `pip` now.
Compare:

current 1.79

```py
    def startNamespaceDeclHandler(self, prefix, uri):
        """Handle start of an XML namespace declaration."""
        if prefix == "xsi":
            # This is an xml schema
            self.schema_namespace = uri
            self.parser.StartElementHandler = self.schemaHandler
        else:
            # Note that the DTD for MathML specifies a default attribute
            # that declares the namespace for each MathML element. This means
            # that MathML element in the XML has an invisible MathML namespace
            # declaration that triggers a call to startNamespaceDeclHandler
            # and endNamespaceDeclHandler. Therefore we need to count how often
            # startNamespaceDeclHandler and endNamespaceDeclHandler were called
            # to find out their first and last invocation for each namespace.
            if prefix == "mml":
                assert uri == "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
            elif prefix == "xlink":
                assert uri == "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unknown prefix '%s' with uri '%s'" % (prefix, uri))
            self.namespace_level[prefix] += 1
            self.namespace_prefix[uri] = prefix
```

GitHub

```py
    def startNamespaceDeclHandler(self, prefix, uri):
        """Handle start of an XML namespace declaration."""
        if prefix == "xsi":
            # This is an xml schema
            self.schema_namespace = uri
            self.parser.StartElementHandler = self.schemaHandler
        else:
            # Note that the DTD for MathML specifies a default attribute
            # that declares the namespace for each MathML element. This means
            # that MathML element in the XML has an invisible MathML namespace
            # declaration that triggers a call to startNamespaceDeclHandler
            # and endNamespaceDeclHandler. Therefore we need to count how often
            # startNamespaceDeclHandler and endNamespaceDeclHandler were called
            # to find out their first and last invocation for each namespace.
            if prefix == "mml":
                assert uri == "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
            elif prefix == "xlink":
                assert uri == "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            elif prefix == "ali":
                assert uri == "http://www.niso.org/schemas/ali/1.0/"
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Unknown prefix '{prefix}' with uri '{uri}'")
            self.namespace_level[prefix] += 1
            self.namespace_prefix[uri] = prefix
```

So you can either exchange or edit **Parser.py** file, or use third party libraries for converting your handle to built-in python object.

---

If you want download just a full text of the article, you could try to download a pdf through `metapub` & go on to extract a text via `textract`.

```py
import metapub
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import textract

pmcid = 'PMC2837563'

fetch = metapub.PubMedFetcher()
article_metadata = fetch.article_by_pmcid(pmcid)

#Get just an abstract
abstract = article_metadata.abstract

#Download full article text
pmid = article_metadata.pmid
url = metapub.FindIt(pmid).url

urlretrieve(url, any_path)

with open(another_path, "w") as textfile:
    textfile.write(textract.process(
        any_path,
        extension='pdf',
        method='pdftotext',
        encoding="utf_8",
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error raised again after I updated biopython. My code with retrieveng xml via esummary performed well, but recently I failed to reproduce results with the same code. I went into the Parser.py code, and now it possesses ali notation. But biopython fails in parsing the xml-formatted output.

Comment: so the solutions is to... what?